# How to insert a modal Login form in the navigation bar

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm building a new website and one of the requirements is to have the login form be a modal window.

I'm trying to include it in the top navigation bar and it's only being rendered if the user is not logged in.

If I delete the model and let an empty modal everything works perfectly but when I add it again it doesn't work, because the model of the page (in  this case the index page) is a different one then the one from the modal login.

How can I add this modal window with it's on model inside the top navbar? Are there any alternatives?

P.S. I'm using Razor Pages and ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a view component:

```
public class LoginViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var model = await GetModelAsync();
        return View(model);
    }

    public Task<LoginViewModel> GetModelAsync() =>
        Task.FromResult(new LoginViewModel());
}
```

Then, create the view `Views\Shared\Components\Login\Default.cshtml` and add your login form code there. Finally, in your layout where you want the login form to be:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Login")
```

You'll need a page or handler that can respond to the form post. You cannot post to a view component; that's just about rendering a partial view with it's own model in a self-contained way that can be dropped in. You should have a hidden input in your login form for a "return URL" which you'll fill with `Request.Path`. Then, on successful login, you redirect the user back to this URL. That way, the login will be seamless, as if they never let the page they were on.

On failure, you should simply redisplay the login form like you would do normally. It's easier and more seamless to just return this as the view. As such, you can piggy-back on the the login page's built-in post handler. Again, just add your return URL field and fill it with the return URL from the request, so that the user will eventually make it back to the page they were initially on when starting the login process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to have this but in a project that only uses Razor Pages?

Comment: It makes no difference.